# How can I add multiple values to a Symfony session as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I'm trying to create a basic 'add to basket' functionality in Syfmony using Ajax. So far I have this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/basket/add")
 */
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $item = [
        'id'     => $request->get('id'),
        'artist' => $request->get('artist'),
        'title'  => $request->get('title'),
        'type'   => $request->get('type')
    ];

    $this->session->set('basket-'.$item['id'], $item);

    return new JsonResponse($this->session->all());
}
```

But ideally I'd have one session set for the basket. I tried previously by trying to use `array_push` in order to append values one by one, but I didn't get very far.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: what's `$this->session`? Shouldn't it be `$request->getSession()`? And also `$request->get()` is not recommended way, it can be slow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this ?

```
public function addSesAction(Request $request)
{
    $basket = $request->getSession()->get('basket', []);
    array_push($basket, [
        'id'     => $request->get('id'),
        'artist' => $request->get('artist'),
        'title'  => $request->get('title'),
        'type'   => $request->get('type')
    ]);
    $request->getSession()->set('basket', $basket);

    return new JsonResponse($basket);
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was after. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I think use should call the session class first, initialize the session first and then try using adding your values to session as array.
Try the following code, hope this will work for you

Try this one:

```
public function addSesAction(Request $request)
{
 $session = new session();
 $item = [
   'id'     => $request->get('id'),
    'artist' => $request->get('artist'),
    'title'  => $request->get('title'),
    'type'   => $request->get('type')
 ];

 $session->set('basket-'.$item['id'], $item);

 return new JsonResponse($session->all());
}
```